# Tkinter AutoEntry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to do an AutoEntry (takes a list of words to provide auto-completion like Google when you do a research) in Tkinter. However, I can't seem to find any simple examples online.

This tutorial mentions AutoEntry at the beginning (http://appjar.info/inputWidgets/) but does not provide an example.

This is an example of an AutoEntry I would like to create: 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbeGf.png)

Anyone has a beginner example ?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334505/how-to-fix-stringvar-get-issue) is an example of auto-completion.

Comment: Thank you. But does it have to be that hard ? There is no already built in function in Tkinter for autocompletion ?

Comment: No, there is no built-in feature to tkinter to do autocompletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something, I think you were looking for...
And you get suggestions in form of buttons so that you can select from it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
l = ['den', 'do', 'dear', 'disco', 'dream']

def select(w):
    global e, f
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, w)
    f.destroy()

def callback(sv):
    global f
    f.destroy()
    f = Frame(root)
    f.pack()
    for words in l:
        entry = e.get()
        print(entry)

        x = words
        y = ''
        for c in x:
            if x.isalpha():
                y += c
                if y == entry:
                    Button(f, text=words, command=lambda word=words: select(word)).grid(sticky=W+E)
                    #Label(f, text=words).pack()
                    print(words)


sv = StringVar()
sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=sv: callback(sv))
e = Entry(root, textvariable=sv)
e.pack()

f = Frame(root)
f.pack()


root.mainloop()
```